# JS API for embedding sheet in Qlik

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

We can embed visuals of a sheet very easily, with:

```js
const vis = await qlikApp.visualization.get('<visual_id>');
vis.show('<visual_container>');  // Renders visual in the given HTML container
```

But, I could not find any such API for embedding Qlik sheet.

In the [docs](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/June2020/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Visualizations/embed-visualization-sheet.htm), I only found embedding sheet by copy pasting iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think its possible to embed the whole sheet using the  [Visualization API](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/June2020/Subsystems/APIs/Content/Sense_ClientAPIs/CapabilityAPIs/VisualizationAPI/VisualizationAPI.htm). This API is targeting specifically visualizations (charts, tables etc.)

The only option I'm aware of is the `iFrame` (aka [Single Interation API](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/June2020/Subsystems/APIs/Content/Sense_ClientAPIs/single-integration-api.htm))

Seems that someone tried to "emulate" Qlik Sense sheet [here](https://gist.github.com/mindspank/047852c7f5247c923354b523cd0c9018). But it looks like this will display only the sheet objects (no selections bar for example).